# Change value of an index in an array, shift indexes starting at old index to the right, while leaving all indexes to the left intact

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an array and I have a new value I want to insert into my array at an index where it will be less than those to the left of it, and greater than those to the right of it. I only care about 10 indexes, old values that get pushed beyond index [9] shall be destroyed.

I tried accomplishing it this way:

```
private double[] scores = {1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1};

public void newScore(double score){

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++){

        if (score > this.scores[i]){
            Array.Copy(this.scores, i, this.scores, i + 1, this.scores.Length - i);
            this.scores[i] = score;
            break;
        }
    }
}

newScore(0.75);

//Desired result: {1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.75, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2};
```

My goal is to get 0.75 inserted between 0.8 and 0.7 while all values less than 0.75 shift right and the old value at `score[9]` to disappear.

I am having issues with the `Array.Copy();` method. Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, or have I made a simple mistake that I cannot find?

I have searched for other solutions but the ones I have found shift all indexes either right or left instead of only values less than the value inserted.

Comment: Does the first value a typo? Should it be `1.0` instead of `0.10`? Is the array sorted?

Comment: Yes I made a typo in the samples. Fixing. The array is not sorted, it is parallel to an array of strings with each index in the string corresponding to a value in the double array.

Comment: In your example array is sorted in descending order. It it just a coincidence or it will be that way? Also what do you mean by "parallel to an array of strings"? In your code there is no string array.

Comment: why not use _List_ instead of _Array_?

Comment: @Zevarix: "The array is not sorted, it is parallel to an array of strings with each index in the string corresponding to a value in the double array." That sounds as if you are looking for a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I left the string array out in the sample since I could apply the solution to the double array to the string array. The string array is a list of names that correspond to the doubles (scores). I save the names and the scores to separate files. When I access the names and the scores, I use `.toString("P1")` to turn `0.75` into `75.00 %` for example. I only care about the top 10 scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.scores.Length - i` with `this.scores.Length - i - 1`.

You have a mistake in your sample: 0.10 = 0.1, it's the poor score.

Original score array would be {**1.0**, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1}

Comment: I've made the change to `this.scores.Legth - i - 1`. And it fixed my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to have an array, I would change the code to:

```
    private List<double> scores = new List<double> { 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 };

    public void newScore(double score) {
        scores.Add(score);
        scores = scores.OrderByDescending(o => o).Take(scores.Count - 1).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: Yes. I realised my mistake just before reading your comment. Well spotted.

Comment: My answer was a round about way of doing a easy thing:) Deleted it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your initial array is wrong. The first value should be 1.0, not 0.1.

I would solve it this way.

```
public void newScore(double score)
{
    var result = new double[this.scores.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.scores.Length; i++)
    {
        if (score > scores[i])
        {
            Array.Copy(this.scores, 0, result, 0, i);
            Array.Copy(this.scores, i, result, i + 1, this.scores.Length - i);
            result[i] = score;
            break;
        }
    }

    scores = result;
}
```